# 未ログイン時のトップページと質問投稿ページに英語の箇所が残っている

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳

### 不具合事象

未ログイン時の[トップページ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/)と[質問投稿ページ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)に英語の箇所が残っています。

#### トップページの未翻訳箇所

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### 質問投稿ページの未翻訳箇所

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

---

### 原因

単語の大小文字や、文章内容の若干の変化などによって、日本語が英語に戻ってしまったことが原因だと思われます。そのため、ほとんどの文章は [ja.traducir.win](https://ja.traducir.win) に類似の文章の翻訳が存在しています。

#### 類似の文章とその翻訳

> **Original String**: Explore Our Questions
>   **Current Translation**: 質問を見る

---

> **Original String**: Browse More Questions
>   **Current Translation**: 質問をもっと見る

---

> **Original String**: Email (required, but never shown)
>   **Current Translation**: メールアドレス（必須ですが、公開はされません）

---

> **Original String**: Feed of recent questions
>   **Current Translation**: 最近の質問のフィード

---

> **Original String**: By using our site, you acknowledge that you have read and understand our `$cookiePolicyStart$`Cookie Policy`$linkEnd$`, `$privacyPolicyStart$`Privacy Policy`$linkEnd$`, and our `$tosStart$`Terms of Service`$linkEnd$`.
>   **Current Translation**: このサイトを利用することによって、あなたはこのサイトの`$cookiePolicyStart$`Cookie Policy`$linkEnd$`、`$privacyPolicyStart$`Privacy Policy`$linkEnd$`、および`$tosStart$`Terms of Service`$linkEnd$`を読んで理解し、同意したものとみなします。

Comment: 翻訳フローの確認なのですが、 https://ja.traducir.win を使った翻訳はどなたでも翻訳文字列を提案して頂けます。サイトの意図に大きく影響しない範囲であればメタへの投稿なしに Traducir 上で直接翻訳を提案していただいても OK です :)　今回の例は、どれも Traducir に該当 string があるようです。

Comment: 補足すると、「ja.traducir.win/ を知っている」かつ「翻訳対象の文字列が traducir に存在する」なら、直接翻訳の提案を出してもらった方が、反映までの時間やみんなの負担が減るのかなと思います。 / traducir では翻訳できない箇所や、訳が思いつかない、検討や議論が必要そうなものはメタで提案して貰う形でOKだと思います。

Comment: @nekketsuuu さん >  Traducir について教えていただき、ありがとうございます。[ja.traducir.win](https://ja.traducir.win) は対訳集だと思っていたのですが、翻訳の提案も出来るのですね。既に当該文字列は翻訳されているようなので、次の機会から [ja.traducir.win](https://ja.traducir.win) を利用しようと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

未ログイン時の[トップページ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/)と[質問投稿ページ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)の未翻訳箇所に日本語訳が反映されたことを確認したので、そのスクリーンショットをもってこの質問を解決済みにしたいと思います。対応いただき、ありがとうございました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]